# Why pandas.merge() is generating additional rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 5 datasets I want to unify. The thing is that in some of them data may be missing or they might not be synchronised(timestamp shifted). I thought about merging all the Timestamp columns to obtain a common Timestamp column.

```py
  temp_1 = pd.merge(a["Timestamp"],a1["Timestamp"],how='outer',on='Timestamp').sort_values(by="Timestamp").reset_index(drop=True)
  temp_2 = pd.merge(a2["Timestamp"],a3["Timestamp"],how='outer',on='Timestamp').sort_values(by="Timestamp").reset_index(drop=True)
  temp_3 = pd.merge(temp_1["Timestamp"],temp_2["Timestamp"],how='outer',on='Timestamp').sort_values(by="Timestamp").reset_index(drop=True)
  temp_4 = pd.merge(temp_3["Timestamp"],a4["Timestamp"],how='outer',on='Timestamp').sort_values(by="Timestamp").reset_index(drop=True)
```

When I print all the lenghts of my datasets I see that the lengths have changed.

```py
print(len(a),len(a1),len(a2),len(a3),len(a4),len(temp_1),len(temp_2),len(temp_4))

52561 52561 52560 52561 52560 52573 52573 52742
```

If we see only to temp_1 datataset, the increase in row could indicate that the Timestamp values are different, so I check if it's with the following lines of code.

```py
(a['Timestamp']==a1['Timestamp']).all()

True
```

Here I can see that both columns are the same.

How can this be possible? If the "Timestamp" columns are the same, merge should give a dataframe with the same lenght.

Best regards,
Ipa.

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE]?

Comment: This could happen if you have duplicate timestamps. Can you check `a['Timestamp'].duplicated().any()`?

Comment: You here right @IanS, I had 6 duplicated values and when I merged it with the other dataset, the duplicates were multiplied by 2. Thank you very much!!